# Firebase doc.data() is an object not a string

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have been getting this error for a while now

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, msg}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I have figured out the culprit:

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("msgs")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setMessages(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            msg: doc.data(),
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);
```

doc.data() is an object not a string so when I go out to render it like this:

```
{messages.map((msg, id) => {
    return (
      <Message key={id} msg={msg} />
    );
})}
```

it throws the error above.

I am following this github repo: https://github.com/leopaul29/facebook-messenger-clone/blob/master/src/App.js

Any ideas?

Comment: could you show the value of  `id` and `data` ?

Comment: When I console.log(doc.data()) it returns an object with the string "hello" (which is what I typed in the text box). When I console.log(id) it comes back with 0, 1, 2, 3... Which is the number associated with the message being sent. This is all using firebase firestore. Doc.data() should be working but it just isn't.

Answer (score -1):

so instead of using doc.data() try using doc.get(and here the data you want to convert )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).